# How to create a multidimensional list of a variable amount of dimensions in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a function that will make a multidimensional list taking an input number to choose the amount of dimensions the list will be. This is my code so far:

```
def createMultiDimList(dimensions, currentDim=0, output=[]):
    if currentDim < dimensions:
        output.append([])
        currentDim += 1
        createMultiDimList(dimensions, currentDim, output[0])
        return output
    else:
        return output
```

I think this isn't working because the recursion is just putting in the single dimensional list, but I am not sure on that.

Comment: whats your result?

Comment: Are you unsure *if* it is working or *why* it isn't working?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am unsure why it isn't working or what I can do to fix it

Comment: @adirabargil I tested it and the result is a single dimensional array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it IMO.  The general idea behind recursion is to solve the easiest case first, and then return the result of the more difficult case in terms of an incrementally easier case.

For this function, the "easy case" is that a 1-dimensional list is `[]`.  The incrementally easier case is that an `n`-dimensional list is an `n-1`-dimensional list inside a list.  Hence:

```
>>> def n_dim_list(n: int) -> list:
...     if n == 1:
...         return []
...     return [n_dim_list(n-1)]
...
>>> n_dim_list(4)
[[[[]]]]
```

If you wanted to complicate it a bit to make it a more interesting example of recursion, you could define a filler value for the 1-dimensional lists and the length of each list:

```
>>> def n_dim_list(n: int, length: int = 0, value = None) -> list:
...     if n == 1:
...         return [value] * length
...     return [n_dim_list(n-1, length, value) for _ in range(length or 1)]
...
>>> n_dim_list(4)
[[[[]]]]
>>> n_dim_list(4, 2, 0)
[[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]]
```

Comment: So is the problem with my code that the appending just appends a list to the list, then when I pass that list to the function it's just passing the list within the list and it'll just return a single dimension list in the end?

Comment: The big problem that I see with your code is that you're using a mutable default argument, and mutating it.  (This is the most common Python "gotcha" -- see https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/)  You don't need to do *either* of those things, though -- there's no reason to pass the list into the function, and there's no reason to mutate it as you go.  As I said, you're overcomplicating it, and unnecessary complexity is where most bugs come from.  :)

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

as @Samwise wisely said, you have simpled awesome approuch like his, specifically for your issue,
you need to send down nested list instead of appending item and returning it:

```
def createMultiDimList(dimensions, currentDim=0, output=[]):
    if currentDim < dimensions:
        currentDim += 1
        createMultiDimList(dimensions, currentDim, [output])
        return output
    else:
        return output
```